Computing polynomial relation ideals (for model invariants)
I have a finite list of polynomials in several variables. For example, $L=\{ab,ac,cd,bd,\cdots\}.$
I am interested in finding model invariants, which I understand to be polynomial relations among the elements of this list. For example, an invariant of the list above is $L_1 \cdot L_3 - L_2 \cdot L_4$, which equals $ab \cdot cd - ac \cdot bd$, and is thus zero for all the parameterization of variables $a,b,c,d,\cdots$.
The set of all such polynomial relations forms an ideal in the polynomial ring. Specifically, I want to:

Identify the ideal of model invariants among my input polynomials.
Compute a generating set for this ideal, i.e., find a finite set of generators that define it.

My questions are: Is the problem above solvable? If so, are there known algorithms for it, and are there softwares (preferably in python) as implementations?
Any pointers, references, or relevant examples would be much appreciated! (I should mention that I have no prior background in algebraic geometry or statistics).

I know that Gröbner bases can help compute generating sets (step 2) if the ideal is already known (step 1), and there are softwares like Macaulay 2 for it. However, in my case, the ideal is unknown.

In algebraic geometry and commutative algebra, these kinds of relations are typically referred to in the literature as syzygies. If you've been struggling to find anything, that may help.

It is a standard elimination technique: to compute the ideal of polynomial relations among the $\,L_i\,$ simply contract the ideal $\,(L_1 - ab, L_2 - ac,\ldots)\,$ to $\,k[L_1,L_2,\ldots]\,$ using Gröbner bases with the appropriate elimination ordering (to eliminate all variables $\,a,b,\ldots\,$ except for the $\,L_i)$.
The $L_i$ are sometimes called tag-variables. The use of this elimination method in ideal standard basis computation dates back to David Spear's independent discovery of Gröbner bases while working in the MIT Mathlab (Macysma) group, mid 1970s (but the idea itself is likely much older).
Below is Teo Mora's description of this elimination method, excerpted from from his excellent book Solving Polynomial Equation Systems, vol. II.



Thank you. The idea here is beautiful! Follow-up questions: say the size of the minimal generating set of such elimination ideal is k. Then, which of the following claims are true? 1. Knowing any arbitrary k entries in L can determine the rest. 2. There exists a specific k entries in L, knowing which can determine the rest. 3. The rank of the Jacobian matrix of L on parameters <a,b,c,d,...> equals k (i.e., understand k as the model L's dimension). Thank you (I know those questions are very basic, and any pointers are appreciated)!

I guess the answer is neither. What I was asking is related to Krull dimension, the dimension of the variety defined by the ideal.

@graphitump Please ask any further questions in new posts, not in comments (the site works much better that way).
